# VUE favicon.ico on IE11 is not showing up properly.(disappearing when router changes)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js, favicon

Favicon on IE showing up randomly. when I change router-view some pages are okay but some pages not. Interesting thing is when I refresh the page then it appears but not all of pages.

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

I tried both codes and even programmatically add .ico file to my very first 
`<head>` tag of `Index.html`. but none of them working properly

Does document.title effects to favicon status? cause I have dynamically changing document.title in my Router Hook.

Comment: Can you check the network tab of developer tools to check whether favicon file get loaded or not when it is not display on page? Check what status code it show for it. Also check that it is placed on correct place and your page able to fetch it after routing the request. also try to make a test with PNG image.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. If I navigate directly to the sites via url, the favicon is shown, but changing views via router-link makes it disappear